# Unable to load XMLTYPE datatype from oracle into the Spark SQL

Tags: java, hbase, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have 67 Million `Oracle` records with some columns `XMLType` as a datatype.

I am using `Spark SQL` to extract all the records from the `Oracle` but I am getting

> datatype unsupported error

in the Spark console.

How to change the `XMLType` so that it  can successfully load it into `Spark SQL`?

My plan is to load all these records from `Oracle` to the `Apache HBase` I am using `Spark SQL` to load the load the into the `Apache HBase`.

Comment: We are also looking to resolve same issue, Please update us if you got any solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the spark xml support library following are the co-ordinates

> groupId: com.databricks artifactId: spark-xml_2.11 version: 0.4.1

then you can get XML file as a dataframe like :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
        .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
        .option("rowTag", "book")
        .load("books.xml")
```

For more information have look [XML Data Source for Apache Spark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)

Once you convert it into dataframe you can do spark sql on the dataframe.